# Sound sometimes does not work for some programs in Windows 7, even from Mixer dialog

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, audio, remote-desktop

In my Windows 7, the sound works for some programs sometimes but not for other, and for those other programs, sometimes it works, sometimes not, with the change happening without reboot. Here:

[image]

if I click on System Sounds slider, it shows the green bar and gives the sound. If I click on Firefox or Remote Desktop slider, nothing happens: no green bar shown, no sound played. And no sound played from those two programs.

Sometimes it works, sometimes not: some hours ago it worked, more hours ago it didn't, now doesn't again. No reboot or device changes since that.

What is more, the Remote Desktop sometimes appears on this dialog and sometimes does not.

I suspect the changes are connected with logging in and out of Remote Desktop. I did not plug or unplug any devices. I noted that Remote Desktop appeared on this dialogue after the computer went to sleep with Remote Desktop connected, then after it woke up and automatically re-connected Remote Desktop, it appeared on the dialogue. Before this, Firefox appeared, but the sound did not work, but Remote Desktop did not appear. And at some moment before, sound in both Firefox and Remote Desktop worked. No reboot since that time, no devices connected or disconnected, though Remote Desktop loses connection and re-connects periodically.

How to fix this? How to force a program to appear on this dialogue? How to make it react on a click on the slider?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to reset the audio driver on the remote system: from an elevated prompt, do

```
net stop  audiosrv
net start audiosrv
```

I made a batch file for this, because I have to do this each time I connect to the remote host.

I also have to close and launch again an AHK script that uses sound, otherwise it still did not emit any sound even after I reset the driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my pc today (Windows 8.1).

More specifically, one program was no longer playing sounds although other were.  Also, the green bar on the sound mixer was going up and down for the program that wasn't playing the sound but to spite that I could not hear any sound from it.  This would even happened after a reboot.

After some searching, I found that windows saves the sound levels that it maps to specific programs in the windows registry.  In short, what I did was force a delete of all these mappings in the registry and did a reboot for good measure!

The end result of this was that all my programs were reset to playing at 100% - including the one I was having problems with.  The one I was having problems with now works fine as do the others.

To reset the registry I put the following into a file called "fix.bat" which I then ran with administrator privileges:

> NET STOP Audiosrv
>
> NET STOP AudioEndpointBuilder
>
> REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore" /F
>
> REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore"
>
> NET START Audiosrv
>
> NET START AudioEndpointBuilder

Hope this will be of help to others.